# trouble with dots using rails paperclipftp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got trouble with paperclipftp

Here my config :

```
has_attached_file :resume_img, :styles => { :thumb => "100x100#",:screen => '690x780#' },:retina => { :quality => 70 },
                    :path => "username.com/uploads/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :url => "http://username.com/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :storage => :ftp,
                    :ftp_credentials => { :host => 'ftp.username.com', :username => 'username', :password => '*******' },
                    :ftp_passive_mode => false,
                    :ftp_timeout => 90,
                    :ftp_verify_size_on_upload => false,
                    :ftp_debug_mode => false
```

My FTP is hosted by dreamhost, I need to upload inside the folder `username.com` but something strange appears rails escape the dots so it upload to `usernamecom/uploads/`

It does the same with the url it try to find the image at `http://usernamecom/`

Any idea???

Comment: no I m not using Fog, should I?

Answer (score 0):

Try it maybe escaped with

```
"username\.com/uploads/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```